ML RL with neural network on Asteroids Game
I have built a DQ network ,which analyses the states of asteroids and the rocket gives out the best possible action to be performed (left, right ,shoot , idle).But the agent keeps spamming bullets ?
can anyone help me in solving this problem ?
I thought the agent would explore all 4 actions but it keeps spamming bullets and harldy moves left or right ,stays almost at the centre and keeps spamming bullets .

There a 2 points you should consider.

Arrange rewards and penalties. When you are creating your policy, don't just give rewards to shooting asteroids, experiment with different states. Give high penalties for shooting when there isn't an asteroid on the same x axis, and give a high reward to shooting where there is an asteroid on that axis. Give penalties for present asteroids, and give rewards when you get closer to an asteroid on x-axis, etc. These are examples ofcourse, you need to emperiment and think on your problem to come up with smart rewards/penalties.
Exploration vs Exploitation The action that has the biggest reward on the current state may not be the best action in the long-term. You need to experiment with your epsilon value to push the model into exploration.

